# How to make PowerPoint (PPApp) appearing immediately behind Excel window?

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I am using a progress form that runs on top of an Excel worksheet.

The progress indicates that Excel objects are exported to PowerPoint.

During the export I want the Excel window to resize such that PowerPoint will also be visible at the left.

I am using the following code for resizing Excel. The problem is how to make PowerPoint (PPApp) appearing immediately behind Excel?

```
With xlApp
.WindowState = xlNormal
.Left = 200
End With
```

Comment: Why the winforms tag? That's for the .NET platform (not VBA)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Public Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
Public Const SWP_DRAWFRAME = &H20
Public Const SWP_FRAMECHANGED = &H20        '  The frame changed: send WM_NCCALCSIZE
Public Const SWP_HIDEWINDOW = &H80
Public Const SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10
Public Const SWP_NOCOPYBITS = &H100
Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Public Const SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = &H200      '  Don't do owner Z ordering
Public Const SWP_NOREDRAW = &H8
Public Const SWP_NOREPOSITION = &H200
Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Public Const SWP_NOZORDER = &H4
Public Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40

Public Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long
```

**Set Position**

```
Sub Main()

    On Error Resume Next
    HWND_TOPMOST = -1

    CmdLine = Command()

    A = Split(CmdLine, Chr(32), 2, 1)
    B = Split(A(0), "x", 2, 1)

    hwindows = FindWindow(vbNullString, A(1))
    Ret = SetWindowPos(hwindows, HWND_NOTOPMOST, B(0), B(1), 0, 0, SWP_NOREPOSITION + SWP_NOSIZE)
    If Ret = 0 Then MsgBox "Set Pos Error is " & Err.LastDllError

End Sub
```

**Set Size**

```
Sub Main()

    On Error Resume Next
    HWND_TOPMOST = -1

    CmdLine = Command()

    A = Split(CmdLine, Chr(32), 2, 1)
    B = Split(A(0), "x", 2, 1)

    hwindows = FindWindow(vbNullString, A(1))
    Ret = SetWindowPos(hwindows, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, B(0), B(1), SWP_NOREPOSITION + SWP_NOMOVE)
    If Ret = 0 Then MsgBox "Set Pos Error is " & Err.LastDllError

End Sub
```

To set active window use this API call from the program that is already the active window

SetForegroundWindow
The SetForegroundWindow function puts the thread that created the specified window into the foreground and activates the window. Keyboard input is directed to the window, and various visual cues are changed for the user. The system assigns a slightly higher priority to the thread that created the foreground window than it does to other threads.

```
BOOL SetForegroundWindow(
  HWND hWnd   // handle to window
);
Parameters
hWnd 
[in] Handle to the window that should be activated and brought to the foreground.
```